# Mosquitto installation in My Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, mqtt, mosquitto

I want to install Mosquitto in My Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mosquitto-dev/mosquitto-ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mosquitto-clients
```

but I have an error testing the installation:

```
devuser@localhost:~$ mosquitto_sub -t '$SYS/#' -v
Error: Connection refused
```

pinging the host from outside is fine:

```
ping 199.162.221.117
PING 199.162.221.117 (199.162.221.117): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 199.162.221.117: icmp_seq=0 ttl=55 time=102.234 ms
```

but not

```
ping 199.162.221.117:1883
ping: cannot resolve 199.162.221.117:1883: Unknown host
```

also

```
devuser@localhost:~$ sudo start mosquitto
[sudo] password for devuser: 
start: Unknown job: mosquitto
```

also

```
devuser@localhost:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/mosquitto start
sudo: /etc/init.d/mosquitto: command not found
```

Comment: Try just using mosquitto as described in https://jsenthilnathanlinux.wordpress.com/2015/03/18/how-to-install-mosquitto-mqtt-on-ubuntu/ and look at this too: https://lukeisadog.wordpress.com/2014/02/27/setting-up-mqtt-on-ubuntu-round-1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only installed the mosquitto command line clients (mosquitto_sub & mosquitto_pub) not the actual broker

```
$ sudo apt-get install mosquitto
```

That should install the actual broker which you will then be able to start with the last command you listed